# ObjectInputStream.read() returning -1, but readObject returns the object

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, ehcache, objectinputstream

Am to serialize an object and deserialize the object but I get:

1. 0 for available()
2. -1 for read()
3. EOFException for readByte()

   ```
   public static Element getCacheObject(String key, String cacheName, String server) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, ConnectException {
       String url = StringUtils.join(new String[] { server, cacheName, key}, "/");
       GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
       ObjectInputStream oin = null;
       InputStream in = null;
       int status = -1;
       Element element = null;
       try {
           status = httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
           if (status == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND) { // if the content is deleted already               
               return null;
           }
           in = getMethod.getResponseBodyAsStream();
           oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
           System.out.println("oin.available():" + oin.available()); // returns 0
           System.out.println("oin.read():" + oin.read()); // returns -1
           element = (Element) oin.readObject(); // returns the object
       }
       catch (Exception except) {
           except.printStackTrace();
           throw except;
       }
       finally {
           try {
               oin.close();
               in.close();
           }
           catch (Exception except) {
               except.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       return element;
   }
   ```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The intention for using `read()` and other methods (including `readFully()` ) was to be able to reconstruct the object in case `readObject()` throws `InvalidClassException`. However, it appears only `readObject()` on `ObjectInputStream` gives expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you see this behaviour because you first create `ObjectInputStream` from `InputStream` and only then check `available` on `InputStream`. If you check constructor of `ObjectInputStream` you can see following:

```
public ObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    verifySubclass();
    bin = new BlockDataInputStream(in);
    handles = new HandleTable(10);
    vlist = new ValidationList();
    enableOverride = false;
    readStreamHeader();
    bin.setBlockDataMode(true);
}
```

There is a method `readStreamHeader` that reads header from input stream. So it is possible that all data is read from `InputStream` during construction of `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: I have also tested with `available()` & `read()` on `ObjectInputStream` instead of `InputStream` but the result is same.

Comment: @JMOkomba you should test `available` and `read` before you create `ObjectINputStream` because I think constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads all data.

Comment: @JMOkomba also keep in mind that invocation of `read` may spoil stream because `ObjectInputStream` won't get this byte and fail to parse object.

Comment: you're right. If I call `available()` and `read()` before creating `ObjectInputStream` it gives result

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `available and read` on `in` variable but `readObject` on `oin` variable.

Comment: I have changed `available()` & `read()` to call `oin` instead of `in`. However, the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

You are at EOS on the stream that is telling you so. There are zero bytes `available()` to be read without blocking; `read()` returns -1 indicating EOS; `readLine()` would return null; and `readXXX()` throws EOFException for any other XXX indicating EOS as well; and `readObject()` returns an `Object` becauase you're reading the `ObjectInputStream`, which is buffered, instead of the stream you called all those other methods on. NB you shouldn't call `read()` just to test for EOS; and `available()` isn't a valid test for EOS in the first place: see the Javadoc.

Comment: Why `available` isn't valid test for EOS? What is valid then? According to javadoc `available` should return 0 if it reached end of stream.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov Because it only tells you how many bytes can be read *without blocking.* A return value of zero therefore has at least two meanings. The only way to detect EOS is to try to read.

Comment: I understand your point. But javadoc for Returns says following: `an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking or 0 when it reaches the end of the input stream.`. So it sasy it returns 0 *when it reaches the end*. I think it's pretty confusing.

Comment: Ah, ok. I understood it. I read it like "0 only when it reaches end" before. Now I've understood that it means more "when it reaches end it returns 0", no "only".

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov It can actually mean three things if not more. 1: there nothing available to be read without blocking (but there might be terabytes between this point and the end of the stream); 2: end of stream; 3: this implementation of `InputStream` didn't implement `available()` (for example, an input stream obtained from an `SSLSocket`).